# make configurable product options independent on product view page --Magento

Tags: magento, product, configurable

I am working on a Magento project and I need to know if there is a way to make a product's options independent to each other or unrequired. I need to use one of several at a time (I have 6 dropdowns).

I have tried add to cart by query string but all dropdown values were still required. I also tried to make all the options default, then modify the selected options in the observer, but I did not meet with success. See the screenshot below for more details.

Any help will be appreciated

[Screenshot http://secure.justhost.com/~sharpwe1/img/imf.png](http://secure.justhost.com/~sharpwe1/img/imf.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because URL in the question is no longer available — 406 error.

Answer (score 0):

Configurable Products in Magneto are only parent products of Simple Products. Whatever you have as an attribute of a Configurable - a Simple Product **has to be** present for each. To do this out of the box in Magento, you should be looking into setting up a Simple Product with Custom Options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.by Simple products with custom options,we can't record inventory.purchased order will not record that option and I need that

Comment: @Irphan I'm afraid in that case you will need to extend Magento to do what you want it to do with something like: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html

Comment: Yes,but to extend magento is tough and time consuming.I am looking if someone have any about this ? can you plz tell me from where magento check that all option are selected correctly ? Because I have tried to      adding product to cart by query string by setting all values.Its adding product to cart fine but if I miss one more options ,it does not add product to cart.like 
http://localhost/lovehome11june/index.php/checkout/cart/add?product=20&qty=1&super_attribute[142]=3&super_attribute[143]=7&super_attribute[144]=11&super_attribute[145]=15&super_attribute[146]=19&super_attribute[147]=27

Comment: @Irphan sorry but you're not doing this a standard way and I cannot advise you on this.